# How can I call call back function of a package from provider in flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
  CSCPicker(
                        showCities: false,
                        onCountryChanged: (country) {
                          List<String> parts = country.split(" ");
                          String code = parts.first;
                          String name = parts.last;
                          stateAction.updateCountry(name, code);
                        },
                        onStateChanged: (stateName) {
                          if (stateName != null) {
                            stateAction.updateCity(stateName);
                          }
                        },
                        onCityChanged: (value) {},
                      ),
```

The above code is perfectly working for new entry but when I am going to edit the existing record, the state is disabled. Hence I have to change the country first. So is there any way to trigger `onCountryChanged` of `CSCPicker` widget from provider class at initial state ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `defaultCountry` property of `CSCPicker` with the selected country - this way you should have it preselected on change.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
import 'package:csc_picker/csc_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  CscCountry? initialCountry;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initialCountry = CscCountry.Aland_Islands;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CSCPicker(
      defaultCountry: initialCountry,
      showCities: false,
      onCountryChanged: (country) {
        List<String> parts = country.split(" ");
        String code = parts.first;
        String name = parts.last;
        // your action => stateAction.updateCountry(name, code);
      },
      onStateChanged: (stateName) {
        if (stateName != null) {
          // your action => stateAction.updateCity(stateName);
        }
      },
      onCityChanged: (value) {},
    );
  }
}
```